Can't read in Realtime Database
I'm using Realtime Database to read and write some data in Firebase.
The code for writing works perfectly and so does the authentication step, but when trying to read it skips the code. I obviously have both read/write flags in true.
Here is the code:
val database = Firebase.database(URL)
val mDatabase = database.reference
var id = intent.getStringExtra("id")
var bundle = Bundle()

mDatabase.child("Users").child(id.toString()).child("user").get()
    .addOnSuccessListener {

        if (it.exists()) {
            bundle.putString("user", it.child("user").value.toString())
            bundle.putString("email", it.child("email").value.toString())
        }
    }
    .addOnFailureListener {
        Log.e("Firebase", "Error")
    }

The id is taken from a previous intent and it is returned fine. When I debug it, the code is just skipped, so I guess it is not accessing the database
I've also tried the following code, but got the same results, where it doesn't even go inside the method:
mDatabase.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {       
    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {    
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            bundle.putString("user", snapshot.child("Users").child(id.toString()).child("user").value.toString())
            bundle.putString("email", snapshot.child("Users").child(id.toString()).child("email").value.toString())
        }
    }

    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {            
    }
})

The database looks like this:
- URL
  - Users
    - id
      - user
      - email


The code looks OK at first glance, so it's likely something we can't see right now. Please edit your question to (1) show how you initialize URL, (2) log id and show that code and its output, and (3) show the JSON from your database (as JSON text, no screenshots please) of node Users in your database (you can export this JSON from the Firebase console).

Also note that bundle.putString(...) does nothing we can easily check. It's best of you Log.i the values, and check (and include) the log output - so that we're all looking at the same things here.
